# How to remember what user user was clicked?

Tags: php, html, forms

How to write a code which will remember when user click on picture "Vlado.jpg" and continue on form "forma_id"?
I need this information becouse when user submite form i will use this in my php.script in if block.

```
<html>
    <div class="tab-pane fade Osiguranje_id">
        <div class="container cont_osiguranje">
            <div class="jumbotron jumb_osiguranje">
                <a id="Osiguranje_id"><h2>Odaberi zastupnika</h2></a>
            </div>

            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#forma_id"><img src="Vlado.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" name="vlado"></a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>


    <div id="forma_id" class="tab-pane fade">             
        <div class="container cont_forma">
            <div class="jumbotron jumb_forma">
                <a id="forma_id"><h2>Ispunite formu:</h2></a></br>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="proba4.php" method="POST">   

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ime">Ime:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" required class="form-control" name="ime" placeholder="Ime"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji"/></div>   
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use Javascript?

Comment: may you reduce your example to the necessary part (and btw. use english as language as it is easier to understand for more people). You could also specify your question as I don't get what you need the functionality for...

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to create a hidden input in your form, and by default it's false, or has some other value (that means didn't click the img - for your situation), when the user clicks the image, use Javascript to change this hidden input value to true (or to a value that means they did click the img - for your situation).